# Generating a string of a specific length, then filling with a value

Tags: ruby, string

I am attempting to take a value `x` and generate a string with the length `x` so that I will have a value like `"00000"`. I want to manipulate those values and return a value such as `"22222"`, `"11111"`, or `"00000"`. I attempted manipulating an array, and I will do an array if necessary, but I prefer to avoid that as that seems to get unnecessarily lengthy.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What kind of value is `x`?

Comment: How do you know whether to return `"22222"` or `"11111"`, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "do an array"?

Comment: I don't understand the question either, but you can generate a string of a specific length by simply multiplying the String by the specified length. Here's an example: `"0" * 5 = "00000"`

Comment: @Alexander You mean, "string of a specific length".

Comment: I just figured he wanted random strings of a specified length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def string_gen(length.to_i)
  chars = %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u w x y z)
  random_string = chars.to_a[rand(chars.length)].join
  puts random_string
end

string_gen(6)
#<= "jahsyd"
```

If you want to do it more then one time add a `.times` loop:

```
def string_gen(length.to_i)
  chars = %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u w x y z)
  5.times do
    random_string = chars.to_a[rand(chars.length)].join
    puts random_string
  end
end
```

This is completely untested.